# ADO.NET Entity Framework multiple statement in where clause or a grouped lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, lambda, where-clause

I am new to the ADO.NET Entity Framework Model. Using DotNet Framework 3.5

I have two tables :

viz. **customers** and **city**

The customers table refers to a cityname column in the table city (foreign key relationship)

While creating a win c# form i am giving the user to filter customers based on his search choices (viz. name, city, number, etc.) Here is my structure

```
using(DataContext dc = new DataContext())  
{  
    IEnumerable cust = dc.customers;  
    if(name != null)    {  
        cust = cust.Where<customers>(c => c.name == name);
    }  
    if(mobile != null)    {  
        cust = cust.Where<customers>(c => c.mobile == mobile);
    }  
    if(city != null)    {
        cust = cust.Where<customers>(c => c.city.cityname == city); //ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException, since the EntityReference.Load method is not called upon. Quite logical point and I agree to it.
I would like some advice on how to either call the load method in the current architechure. Is it possible to somehow do this :

```
    c.cityReference.Load();
    c.city.cityname == city
```

Or possibly some lambda expression (I am new to it) which induces both the statements? Ne suggestions?
I am ready to change the current architecture if anyone has a better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
IEnumerable cust = dc.customers.Include("city");
```

Check [out this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx) post for reference.

Comment: `<<city>>` is not a type of the property but the name of the property.

Comment: Yes. The reason why it is the name of the property insted of the name of the type is that you can have many navigation properties using the same type.